# NodeJs fs.createWriteStream: 'wx' flag not working

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

I have this method, that starts saving an image from a stream:

```
 saveFromStream() {

    const imageName = this.getImageName();
    console.log('flag of stream:',this.flag);
    this.response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(this.dest + imageName), { encoding: 'binary',flags:this.flag })
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.response.data.on('end', () => {
            resolve()
        })

        this.response.data.on('error', () => {
            reject()
        })
    })
}
```

The "this.flag" comes from user config object. When i pass 'wx', i see that existing files are still being overwritten. I don't understand why. As u can see, i'm passing the flag in the options object.

It works perfectly fine when i use fs.writeFile(which throws an 'EEXIST' error if the file exists), but not with fs.createWriteStream.

Any idea why?

Comment: You're passing the options to `pipe`, not `createWriteStream`.

Comment: Hehe what a silly mistake on my part :D Thank you